# Program/plugin that highlights chunk of code executed every step(C++ / java )

Tags: c++, plugins, ide, dev-c++, codehighlighter

Do you know a program /plugin for C++/java that highlights code my program is running?

Is there any software like that?

Update: **VISUALIZING - SHOWING STACK  **
 once call is done - cleaning stack on screen and going back to the function that called it etc

This is what i mean by this. 
As far as i know NO debugger does viualizing right?

is there any good **VISUAL **debugger that does it?

Comment: Do you mean a debugger?

Comment: Any IDE should have a debugger which would do this.

Comment: @Angew, i mean VISUAL/GRAPHICAL DEBUGGER THAT draws borders of stack and all the information on variables that involved with this specific call.....